# Getting first few characters of a string with applescript

Tags: applescript

I wish to keep only the first 13 caracters of a string in an applescript. I think I didn't understand how to use the "characters" function.
Can someone help me ?

```
choose from list {"0041325677667-pharmacie 1", "0041325677557-pharmacie 2",
"0041325677447-pharmacie 3", "0041325677337-pharmacie 4"} with prompt 
"Thanks to select" without multiple selections allowed and empty selection allowed 
return the result as string 
return characters 1 thru 13 of result
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`characters x thru y` returns a list of characters, in your example item 1 returns

```
{"0", "0", "4" ,"1" ,"3" ,"2" ,"5" ,"6" ,"7" ,"7" ,"6" ,"6", "7"}
```

`text x thru y` returns a string as requested.

`without multiple selections allowed and empty selection allowed` is the default so it can be omitted. But you should consider the case when the user presses "Cancel", then the expression return boolean `false`.

```
set chosen to choose from list {"0041325677667-pharmacie 1", "0041325677557-pharmacie 2", "0041325677447-pharmacie 3", "0041325677337-pharmacie 4"} with prompt "Thanks to select"
if chosen is false then return "" -- in case of 'Cancel' return empty string
return text 1 thru 13 of (item 1 of chosen) -- as chosen returns a list by default it must be flattened
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in case the string is shorter than N characters? Using `characters 1 thru 10 of myString` throws an error if the string is shorter than 10 characters. I want the first N characters, up to 10.

Comment: @d-b No, you have to check if the string is shorter than 10 characters.